# Maximum call stack exceeded mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to save documents into a **mongodb** collection using **mongoose/node.js** with the schema ,

```
var userSchema = {
    userName : String,
    userId : Number,
    Location : [{Country : String}]
};

var mySchema = {
    userData : userSchema,
    title : String
};

var MyModel = mongoose.model('MyModel' , mySchema);
```

However on ,

```
req.MY_user = JSON.parse(res.body); // Response from an API
MyModel.update({title : 'sometitle'} , {userData : req.MY_user , title : 'sometitle'} , 
               {upsert : true} , 
               function(err , raw){ ... });
```

I get an error, ***Maximum call stack exceeded***.

Strangely, it works fine on my local machine running Mac.
Problem arises when deployed to linux/windows.

Any solutions please ?

Eg Response :

```
req.MY_user = { 
 userName : 'John',
 userId : 12345,
 Location : [{Country : 'Rus'} , {Country : 'Ind'}]};
```

Update , adding error.stack,

```
Range Error : at Function.isArray (native),
at shouldFlatten node_modules/mongoose/lib/services/common.js 81:13
at modifiedPaths node_modules/mongoose/lib/services/common.js 65:7 
(above line is repeated  multiple times)
```

Comment: Could you post what's in `req.MY_user`, in case it's significant?

Comment: Can you provide us with the stack trace of the error? If it's of type `Error` it should have a printable `stack` property which will help to figure out whether you just dove into a callback column that went too deep, or if you accidentally wrote some infinite recursion.

Comment: For clarity on why we need the stack trace, [this little posting](http://www.2ality.com/2014/04/call-stack-size.html) shows us some general limits on the call stack under NodeJS for simple code. 11,000 recursive calls may seem like a lot, but that number gets very small if the functions themselves are holding onto a lot of data.